# Display a message if array is empty in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, accordion

I would like to put a message that says the list is empty if it contains nothing. If my table is empty I would like it to display a message like "No group" or "No Category".

My code :

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item-stable" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
      <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
      &nbsp; Group 1 :
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-repeat="item in group track by $index" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
      {{item.groupName}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<div class="spacer" style="width: 283.2px; height: 10px;"></div>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item-stable" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
      <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
      &nbsp; Category :
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-repeat="item in category track by $index" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
      {{item.categoryName}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

in my controller :

```
 $scope.group = [];
 $scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
  $scope.shownGroup = null;
} else {
  $scope.shownGroup = group;
}
};
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ng-if for hide and show "No group" information

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item-stable" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
      <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
      &nbsp; Group 1 :
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-repeat="item in group track by $index" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
      {{item.groupName}}
    </ion-item>
     <ion-item ng-if="group.length">  // hide an show "no Group" part
       No Group
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<div class="spacer" style="width: 283.2px; height: 10px;"></div>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item-stable" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
      <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
      &nbsp; Category :
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-repeat="item in category track by $index" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
      {{item.categoryName}}
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item ng-if="category .length">  // hide an show "no category" part
   No category 
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```